# winapi - Change resolution of display not working

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I'm trying to change resolution of my display using win32 call ChangeDisplaySettings with the following way:

```
DEVMODE devmode;
devmode.dmPelsWidth = 1024;
devmode.dmPelsHeight = 768;

long result = ChangeDisplaySettings(&devmode, DM_PELSWIDTH || DM_PELSHEIGHT);
qDebug() << "RESULT OF CHANGE DISPLAY :"<< result;
```

Always I get the same result value, -2, that indicates "display mode stored in the Registry". The source of this info is the following:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36664/Changing-Display-Settings-Programmatically

The issue here is that my resolution DOES NOT CHANGE never. Any idea why I cannot do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always consult with [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183411.aspx) when using Window API.

This should work:

```
DEVMODE devmode;
devmode.dmPelsWidth = 1024;
devmode.dmPelsHeight = 768;
devmode.dmFields = DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;
devmode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);

long result = ChangeDisplaySettings(&devmode, 0);
```

Comment: Like a charm! Thanks @Stas This solution store the resolution in registry right? If I want to restore a previous resolution, how I need to proceed?

Comment: The solution of the above comment is `ChangeDisplaySettings ( NULL, 0 );`