# Changing Screen Resolution of Computer using python

Tags: python

I'm creating a python program that is supposed to streamline the process of setting up a computer. I want this python program to change the screen resolution of the computer and scaling of it. I'm not sure what the best approach is however, or how to approach it.

I've tried using an example pywin32 program, but it only outputted an array of resolution sizes

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look how to [change screen resolution using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33014154/1084416) and then translated it to Python:

```
import win32api
import win32con
import pywintypes

devmode = pywintypes.DEVMODEType()

devmode.PelsWidth = 1366
devmode.PelsHeight = 768

devmode.Fields = win32con.DM_PELSWIDTH | win32con.DM_PELSHEIGHT

win32api.ChangeDisplaySettings(devmode, 0)
```

We needed a [**`DEVMODE`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-_devicemodea) object to pass to the [**`ChangeDisplaySettings`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsa) function. The `pywintypes` module which is also part of `pywin32` has a function to create objects of type `DEVMODE`.

We then set the `PelsWidth` and `PelsHeight` fields and also the `Fields` field to tell the API which field's values we want to use.

To change back to the previous resolution, simply call:

```
win32api.ChangeDisplaySettings(None, 0)
```

Thanks for asking the question. I've learned something.

Comment: what is the purpose of 0 in the line "win32api.ChangeDisplaySettings(None, 0)"

Comment: @BrandonChiu the linked documentation explains the flag means: *"The graphics mode for the current screen will be changed dynamically"*. However, I don't know what that means. Looking at the other possible values for the flag, it seems the other options are to store the value in the registry, test whether settings are valid, only apply on restart, and change which is the primary screen, etc. So I imagine `0` really means *"don't change anything else and make it temporary"*.

Comment: In the documentation it notes , that "CDS_GLOBAL" can be set as one of the flags.I tried replacing 0 with that flag, and pycharm throws me an unresolved reference. Is there an additional import I should be doing and/or process? Thanks

Comment: @BrandonChiu `CDS_GLOBAL` is defined in the same place as `DM_PELSWIDTH` and `DM_PELSHEIGHT` in `win32con`. Its value is `8`.